# Is there any tool or website to convert Oracle 10g SQL query to SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle10g

I am creating some demo application for Webdev server for this Java WebDAV Server by ithit.com 
They provide me with a SQL query in Oracle 10g datatype format and there are number of queries.

Is there any way to convert this query to format runnable on SQL Server 2005? So that I can use SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this, this may help you.

http://www.swissql.com/products/sql-translator/sql-converter.html

### Update (2016-02-03)

Looks like SwisSQL has been discontinued.

> SwisSQL - End of Life Notice
>
> Thanks for your interest in SwisSQL
>
> Regret to inform you that we have decided to discontinue any development and investments on this product to best align with our business goals and direction. Existing customers of SwisSQL can avail product support from us till their current support contract expires. For further queries, do email us at support@swissql.com and we'll be happy to assist you.